# how to refresh a blackberry qml page?

Tags: blackberry, qml, page-refresh

I am new to Blackberry development. Currently I am having 2 pages **page1.qml** and **page2.qml**. Now I am redirect to page2.qml from page1.qml on a button click using NavigationPane. Now I want to refresh page1.qml when we tap Back button on page2.xml. How i can refresh page.

Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by passing page1 reference to page2.qml and call refresh() of page1.qml from paneProperties of page2.qml like :

Page1.qml

```
 Page{
         id: page1
          .......
          .......
         Button {
            onClicked: {
               var page=page2.createObject()
               page.page1Ref=page1
               navigationpane.push(page)       
            }
        }
     function refresh(){
     // write a code to refresh page1.qml
    }
}


    Page2.qml




Page{
         id: page2
                     property Page page1Ref
                      .......
                      .......
                     paneProperties: NavigationPaneProperties {
                     backButton: ActionItem {
                    onTriggered: {
                      page1Ref.refresh()
                       navigationpane.pop();
                      }
                }
            }
       }
```